# HTML Table to Excel Spreadsheet with excel functions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am looking for a library that converts `HTML` table into an `Excel Spreadsheet` with excel functions.

Is there such an open-source library that I can use?
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

1. TableExport: https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport

   Docs: https://tableexport.v5.travismclarke.com/

---

2. table2excel: https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel

   Article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-html-table-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-jquery/

Comment: Hi @Manas, I am not looking for exporting table to excel file/data. I am looking for a library that converts a `table` into an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, these libraries do the same.